# adding slideshow of images to page

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

When I try to add an image slideshow, idr doesn't work.

This is the HTML element:

```
<img class="main-img" alt="">
```

This is my Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mainImg = document.querySelector('.main-img');
    let slideshow = [
        '../img/jevon_cochran_pelourinho.jpg',
        '../img/jevon_cochran_quibdo.jpg',
        '../img/me_in_Pernambues.JPG'
    ];
    var index = 0;
    var interval = 2000;
    function slide() {
        mainImg.src = slideshow[i];
        index++;
        if (index >= slideshow.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    setInterval(slide, interval);
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: Try changing `mainImg.src = slideshow[i];` to `mainImg.src = slideshow[index];`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! @poushy

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it will be much easier to use a javaScript library like slick to create an image slide show or you can just use bootstrap carousel.

*slick - https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/*

*Carousel - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/*

Hope this helps!